# detached entity passed to persist - springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Sales Order save not working for existing Customer but working for new Customer

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "sales_order")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class SalesOrder extends Auditable<String>  implements Serializable {
    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;
    

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Customer extends Auditable<String>  implements Serializable {
    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="customer",cascade={CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private SalesOrder salesOrder;
```

```java
SalesOrder salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
            Branch branch = BranchContextHolder.getCurrentBranch();
            String nextSequense = null;
            if(salesOrderDto.getId()==null) {
                salesOrder = new SalesOrder(salesOrderDto);
                salesOrder.setBranch(branch);
                if(customerRepository.existsByPhone(salesOrderDto.getCustomer().getPhone())) {
                    Customer customer = customerRepository.findCustomerByPhone(salesOrderDto.getCustomer().getPhone());
                    customer.setSalesOrder(salesOrder);
                    salesOrder.setCustomer(customer);
                }
                nextSequense = sequenceService.getNextSequense(branch.getId(),module.getId());
                salesOrder.setUid(nextSequense);
            }

//save sales order
salesOrder = salesOrderRepository.save(salesOrder);
```

On save getting error:

```
detached entity passed to persist: com.jee.cms.app.customer.model.Customer; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.jee.cms.app.customer.model.Customer
```

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try annotating your method with `@Transactional`. Then then `Customer` won't get detached within the method.

Comment: `
@Transactional("tenantTransactionManager")
I have added top of the save method 

Getting error Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Transactional.TxType
it was multi tenant based architecture

if i  ll add only @Transactional
then
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: masterTransactionManager,tenantTransactionManager
`

Comment: Then you need to configure your application correctly so that the `@Transactional` annotation can be used.

Comment: @JeebendukumarBehera great! Can you please mark the answer as accepted (any maybe upvote as well)? :)

Answer (score 0):

This type of error arise when more then one entry found with same id (@id column value) .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).